# Android + Take video captures of your screen

Tags: android, video-capture

Hey Guys, 
 I am looking for a source code\framework which will allow me to 
record the device's springboard, in other words to "take video 
captures of your screen". 
 Something like 'Display Recorder' for the iPhone, [Link](http://www.ihackintosh.com/2010/05/display-recorder-record-video-of-your-iphone-springboard/).
I already found this project ["capture video"](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/951-how-to-capture-video-of-the-screen-on-android/), but unfortunately it will give low quality video (5/6 FPS)...
Is there any way to improve it?

Kind Regards,

M

Comment: can you post your code? since i too need to record my application screen while its running. when i attempt to download code from link you provide above half of the project is downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Romain Guy posted recently about how he makes recordings of his Honeycomb device, and the solution was to feed the HDMI output into a video recording device attached to a desktop machine.

My suspicion is that if that's what he proposes, there's no way to do it that well on-device. Even if you can access the screen in all scenarios, many devices don't have the power to encode a video stream at good enough speed, which explains why Capture Video is giving such poor results.